# GSON skip class if object in class is empty/null

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm currently writing a permission system for my discord bot.
The problem that I'm facing is that the JSON gets quite full of "empty" objects.

I want to skip objects like these

```
        "userId": {
          "userName": "RandomDiscord Name",
          "permissions": []
        },
```

But keep objects like these

```
        "userId": {
          "userName": "RandomDiscord Name",
          "permissions": [
                "some.permission.string",
                "some.permission.string2",
                "some.permission.string3",
          ]
        },
```

I try to get a `ExclusionStrategy => shouldSkipClass(Class<?> aClass)` where I can check for the content for the that said class. Like

```
@Override
public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> aClass) {
    if(aClass instanceof PermissionUser){
        PermissionUser user = (PermissionUser) aClass;
        return user.getPermissions().isEmpty();
    }
    return false;
}
```

But this won't work since I won't get the instance, only type of class, so I can't cast it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?
(Be nice to me, paramedic by daytime, programming only as a hobby)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found a way todo this.

```
 Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()
                .registerTypeAdapter(PermissionUser.class, new PermissionUserAdapter())
                .registerTypeAdapter(PermissionGroup.class, new PermissionGroupAdapter())
                .setPrettyPrinting().create();
```

The adapter looks like this.

```
public class PermissionUserAdapter implements JsonSerializer<PermissionUser> {
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(PermissionUser src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        if(!src.getPermissions().isEmpty() && src.getPermissions() != null){
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
            return gson.toJsonTree(src);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Quite simple once I got the right direction. If anybody has a better Idea, feel free to correct me.

Comment: * Swap `&&` operands to get rid of potential `NullPointerException`.
* The `serialize` method is better to return `JsonNull.INSTANCE` (see [null-object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern)).
* Creating multiple `Gson` instances every time the `serialize` method is invoked wastes heap. Just make the `Gson` instance `private static final`. `SerializationContext` unfortunately causes `StackOverflowError`.

Comment: If you're interested in a more efficient and flexible solution, please find it here: https://pastebin.com/k6Nbaiff .
The paste at pastebin.com will be disposed in a month.

Comment: Thank you Fluffy! I’ll try it once I get home 